# Getting net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when accessing AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to access my AWS Application Load Balancer(ALB) but I am getting a net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID instead.

Current Scenario:

- ALB has an HTTPS:443 listener (only one listener is present) with an SSL Certificate provided for my domain `example.com` & `*.example.com`.

I would be more than happy to provide any further details required to support my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you accessing it via one of the hostnames valid in the SSL?

Comment: So my domain name is `https://example.com`, it's entry is present in the certificate as `example.com` and `*.example.com`. When I try to access `https://example.com/articles` which makes a call to my ALB `https://alburl/getArticle`, I get the net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error on console.

Comment: Does it work on just `example.com`?

Comment: So my example.com is a static page that is configured by Cloudflare SSL. Its doesn't access my ALB. only /article does

Comment: What happens if you try to resolve your domain via the Load Balancer directly instead of CloudFlare?

Comment: I get the big chrome insecure page screen

Comment: The only way I can access it explicitly is when I hit advanced and then I accept the risk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219856/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to one of the following scenarios:

- The SSL certificate attached to the load balancer does not include the domain you're expecting it to. For wildcards remember that `*.example.com` will only cover a single level subdomain such as `www.example.com` not secondary levels such as `beta.www.example.com`.
- The domain you're accessing with the browser is not supported on the SSL, you need to ensure the SSL is valid for that domain only (if it redirects to another domain or you're trying to access via the load balancer domain name it will not be valid).

You should be able to get some more information about the error by running the below.

```
curl -i -v https://example.com
```

Comment: Used this to debug and got to know I had hardcoded my ALB URL in my React Code. Changing it to my SSL specified domain, example.com worked like a charm! Thanks, Chris for pointing out the error!